# How do I obtain a hash of the payload of a digital photo container, ideally in Java?

Tags: photo, exif, metadata-extractor

I have edited EXIF properties on digital pictures, and would like to be able to identify them as identical. I believe this implies extracting the payload stream and computing a hash. What is the best way to do this, ideally in the Java language, most ideally in Java using a native implementation for performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPEG files are a series of 'segments'. Some contain image data, others don't.

Exif data is stored in the APP1 segment. You could write some code to compare the *other* segments, and see if they match. A hash seems like a reasonable approach here. For example, you might compare a hash of only the SOI, DQT or DHT segments. You'd need to experiment to see which of these gives the best result.

Check out the `JpegSegmentReader` class from my *metadata-extractor* library.

- Java: https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor
- .NET: https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet

With that class you can pull out specific segment(s) from a JPEG for processing.

Let us know how you get on!

Comment: Actually this might make a nice sample app for the library, if you wanted to contribute some code.

Comment: Thanks. That is a hit. Also, everyone else who is reading please note that the MDE is available via this maven coordinate from maven central:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.drewnoakes</groupId>
    <artifactId>metadata-extractor</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. I added the Maven details to the project's README as well, cheers.