# How to access the raw image data

Tags: java, metadata-extractor

I'm using metadata-extractor to write a Java application that organizes images and finds duplicates. The API is great, but there's something I cannot figure out.

Suppose I have two JPG images. These images, visually, are exactly the same (i.e. same pixel-wise). However, maybe something within the metadata encapsulated in the file differs.

If I calculate MD5 hashes on each *complete* file, I will get two different hashes. However, I want to calculate a hash of only the image/pixel data, which would yield the same hash for both files.

So - Is there a way to pull out the raw image/pixel data from the JPG using metadata-extractor so that I can calculate my hash on this?

Also, is Javadoc available for this API? I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: Why are you using md5 hash, wouldn't simply comparing the data in the file be quicker? Also you can see jpeg encoding and get the image data from it's respective chunk.

Comment: Also in my opinion I think if you want to extract a bitmap (x,y to argb) it would be easier to just not use meta data extractor. The process of opening a jpeg as a binary file and parsing the image data chunks seems a shorter process than working out their api. This isn't based on fact but my opinion based on briefly looking at thier api.

Comment: Yes, just comparing the data would be simpler. As I'm not familiar with how to pick through JPGs, I'm not sure how to get at that "respective chunk" that represents the image data.

Comment: There is the jpeg encoding specification. There are header chunks and other chunk types. You need the one which contains the image data (if it isn't compressed). Meta data extractor should abstract you away from all this detail and save you time. But meta data extractor is also desighnwd to handle a wide range of formats making the api probably more complex than the jpeg encoding itself.

Comment: I think you need an adapter that goes from the jpeg binary to a bitmap xml file.

Comment: I could write one tomorrow maybe and post the source here. There should be one available somwhere and the data will be in the xml file.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the library's `JpegSegmentReader` class. It'll let you pull out the JPEG segments that contain image data and ignore metadata segments.

I discussed this technique in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40333475/24874) and the asker indicated they had success with the approach.

This would actually make a nice sample application for the library. If you come up with something and feel like sharing, please do.